# How to debug GeoServer HTTP response code: 400?

Tags: geoserver, coordinate-system, wms, thredds

We are using opengeo 2.4.3, and trying to open some layers with GeoServer through WMS. The different layers in the WMS file are detected, but when doing 'layer preview', we get the following error:

```
'org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.directRasterRender(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:871) 
at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:290) 
... 88 more 
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: 
http://localhost:8080/thredds/wms/conakry.nc?
SERVICE=WMS&
LAYERS=tz&
FORMAT=image%252Fpng&
TRANSPARENT=FALSE&
HEIGHT=512&
BGCOLOR=0xFFFFFF&
REQUEST=GetMap&
WIDTH=512&
BBOX=-21.017490386963,3.9957752227786,-9.0176734924312,15.99559211731& 
STYLES=&
SRS=CRS:84&
VERSION=1.3.0'
```

The thing is that we have previously done this with the GeoServer 2.1.1 version and everything worked fine. We have checked the URL causing the problem, and pasting the URL into a web-browser and changing the 'SRS' bit to CRS bit seems to be working somehow...

Can someone please help us on this issue?

Otherwise, does somebody know how to use another version of GeoServer in the OpenGeo Suite

Answer (score 1):

From the CRS/SRS issue I suspect you have changed the WMS version you are requesting from 1.1.1 to 1.3 - see http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/basics.html#differences-between-wms-versions for a description of the main differences and how to handle the change.

The biggest issue is that the axis order changed for some projections. So you may need to reorder your bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

The URL itself has an error.

This combination is wrong:

```
&SRS=CRS:84&VERSION=1.3.0
```

For a WMS version 1.3.0 request the coordinate reference system parameter is 'CRS' not 'SRS' so here you should have

```
&CRS=CRS:84&VERSION=1.3.0
```

Which is directly equivalent (e.g. no need to change the order of the bounding box coordinates) to:

```
&SRS=EPSG:4326&VERSION=1.1.1
```